# What is the int argument in Sys.mkdir ocaml

Tags: ocaml, file-permissions, mkdir

On [the `Sys` doc](https://ocaml.org/api/Sys.html#VALmkdir) I can see there is a function to create a directory, I guess the `string` argument is the directory's name, however I don't know what the `int` argument is for.

> **`val mkdir : string -> int -> unit`**
> Create a directory with the given permissions. [Since 4.12.0]

It may be related to the second argument of the function of the same name in [`Unix`](https://ocaml.org/api/Unix.html#VALmkdir):

> **`val mkdir : string -> file_perm -> unit`**
> Create a directory with the given permissions (see `Unix.umask`).

But it doesn't help me that much either.

What should I use for this argument if I want to create a directory to create files in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Unix file permission number. It is a 3 * 3 bit vector corresponding to the {execute,write,execute} permission in function of the  the current user (either {owner,group,other}).

On Windows, this argument is ignored and you can probably use `0o755` as a sensible unix default.